# How to fix KeyError: 'Address' in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently learning Data Analysis with Pandas. I was practicing indexing and slicing data frames, and I  imported a CSV file named 'supermarkets.csv' using the read_csv() which was successful. Now I want to slice the data frame but I intend to use the Address Column which is the most unique column in the file as the index using the set_index() function but I keep getting error anytime I update it to a variable. All within Jupyter Notebook.

The Code:

```
import pandas
dframe = pandas.read_csv("supermarket.csv")
dframe.set_index("Address") #the outputted the dataframe with the new index

dframe = dframe.set_index("Address") #this is where the issue keeps coming up
```

The Error Message:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Address'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-469e201b9d49> in <module>
----> 1 dframe.set_index("Address")

c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in set_index(self, keys, drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
   4176                 names.append(None)
   4177             else:
-> 4178                 level = frame[col]._values
   4179                 names.append(col)
   4180                 if drop:

c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Address'
```

I've tried to use this format but to no avail data.set_index('Address',inplace=True)

Comment: After you ```read_csv(...)``` try printing columns of the dataframe you loaded: ```print(dframe.columns)```

Comment: set_index changes the index, and that you do in the 3rd line. I don't think the 4th line makes sense, and is not needed.